# Mips Assembly not skipping functions when using beq problem

Tags: assembly, mips

I put choiceWhat part as a test. When i enter "a", the program skips choiceWhat and goes to choiceA. But when I enter b or c it prints choiceA and then exits the program.

```
# read string input
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, choice
    li $a1, 50
    syscall
    
    # move string to $s6
    move $s6, $a0

    li $s4, 'a'
    li $s5, 'b'
    li $s7, 'c'
    move $s4, $a0
    move $s5, $a0
    move $s7, $a0

    beq $s6, $s4, choiceA # jump to choice a if user chose 'a'
    beq $s6, $s5, choiceB # jump to choice a if user chose 'b'
    beq $s6, $s7, choiceC # jump to choice a if user chose 'c'
    # exit program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

choiceWhat:
    li $v0,4  # syscall 4 prints the string
    la $a0,choice    # get size of the array
    syscall
    j done

choiceA:
    li $v0,4  # syscall 4 prints the string
    la $a0,countMsg    # get size of the array
    syscall
    j done

choiceB:
## display less than
    li $v0,4  # syscall 4 prints the string
    la $a0,lessThanMsg    # get size of the array
    j done

## display divisible
choiceC:
    li $v0,4  # syscall 4 prints the string
    la $a0,divisibleMsg    # get size of the array
    j done

done:
```

Why is beq function is not skipping two functions. I thought maybe it reads everything as "a" and that is why it prints countA no matter what but when i check it, it reads the choice correctly. Is there something I could do?

Comment: What is in `$s6`?

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to add that. It holds user choice which is either 'a', 'b' or 'c'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines

```
    move $s4, $a0
    move $s5, $a0
    move $s7, $a0
```

are harmful.

According to [MIPS Assembly/Pseudoinstructions - Wikibooks, open books for an open world](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Pseudoinstructions),

```
move $1, $2
```

means

```
add $1, $2, $0
```

and it will overwrite the register `$1` by the value in the register `$2`.

Therefore, the lines erase the values `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` stored in the registers `$s4`, `$s5`, and `$s7`.

Remove the harmful lines to let the values `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` be compared with `$s6`.

---

Also note that `$a0` in the system call `read_string` is *an address* of the string, so

```
    # move string to $s6
    move $s6, $a0
```

won't store what the user entered.

To take the first entered character, you should do:

```
    # move first character to $s6
    lbu $s6, 0($a0)
```

Comment: I have tried this before but it completely stops the program, it does not even jump anywhere so i think without move it does not load instruction therefore it completely stops.

Comment: @zedyjy Is the user choice really stored in `$s6`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i have updated the question. $s6 is at the beginning of the code